# Direction of DSE Solr cluster capacity planning

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

Getting started with latest DSE, trying to setup an initial DSE solr cluster and wanting to make sure basic capacity needs are met.  In following docs I have done some initial capacity testing following directions here:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCapazty.html

My test single node setup is on AWS, m3.xl, 80GB raid0 for the two 40GB ssd's, latest DSE installed

I have inserted a total of 6MM example records and run some solr searches which would be similar to that which production would be running.

Have the following numbers for my 6MM records:

```
  6MM Records

  7.6GB   disk (Cassandra + solr)
  2.56GB  solr index size
  96.2MB  solr field cache(totalReadableMemSize)
  25.57MB solr Heap
```

I am trying to plan out an initial starter cluster, would like to plan for around 250MM records stored and indexed to start.  Read load will be pretty minimal in the early days, so not too worried about read throughput to start.

Following the capacity planning doc page and some numbers for 250MM from 6MM looks like base requirements for dataset would be:

```
  250MM Records
  106GB solr index size
  317GB disk (Cassandra + solr)
  4GB solr field cache(totalReadableMemSize)
  1.1GB solr Heap
```

So some questions looking for some guidance on and if I am understanding docs correctly:

Should I be targeting ~360GB+ storage to be safe and not exceed 80% disk capacity on average as data set grows?

Should I use nodes that can allocate 6GB for solr + XGB for Cassandra?  (ie: if entire solr index for 250MM is around 6GB for heap and field cache, and I partition across 3 nodes with replication)

With ~6GB for solr, how much should I try to dedicate to Cassandra proper?

Anything else to consider with planning (will be running on AWS)?

UPDATED (11/6) - Notes/suggestions from phact

With Cass+Solr running together, will target prescribed 14GB for each node for base operation, moving to targeted 30GB memory nodes on AWS, leaving 16GB for OS, solr index, solr field cache

I added the solr index size to numbers above, if suggested target to keep most/all index in memory seems I might need to target AT LEAST 8 nodes to start, with 30GB memory per node.

Seems like a good amount of extra overhead for solr nodes for targeting index in memory, might have to re-consider approach

Answer (score 0):

#### DSE heap on a Solr node

The recommended heap size for a DSE node running solr is 14gb. This is because Solr and Cassandra actually run in the same JVM. You don't have to allocate memory for Solr separately.

#### AWS M3.xl

m3.xl's with 15gb ram will be a bit tight with a 14gb heap. However, if your workload is relatively light, you can probably get away with a 12gb heap on your solr nodes.

#### OS page cache

You do want to make sure that you are able to at least fit your Solr indexes in OS page cache (memory left over after subtracting out your heap -- assuming this is a dedicated box). Ideally, you will also have room for Cassandra to store some of your frequently read rows in page cache.

A quick and dirty way of figuring out how big your indexes are is checking the size of your index directory on your file system. Make sure to forecast out/extrapolate if you're expecting your data to grow. You can also check the index size for each of your cores as follows:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&memory=true
```

**Note** - each node should hold it's index in memory, not the entire cluster's index.

#### Storage

Yes you do want to ensure your disks are not over utilized or you may face issues during compaction. In theory--worse case scenario--tiered compaction could require up to 50% of your disk to be free. This is not common though, see more details [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningDiskCapacity_t.html).

Comment: thanks for detailed reply phact.., couple follow up q's.  Given my 6MM record test, my current index size is 2.56GB, does that mean for even this small 6MM data set it would be prudent for me to have 14GB for the JVM heap for Cass/Solr.., and another ~2.5GB for the index to fit in memory?  does the field cache mean anything?.., was following the directions on solr node capacity planning, mention field cache specifically, not sizing to fit entire index in os page cache

Comment: To quote the solr docs directly you want enough ram so that "the important parts of your index, or ideally your entire index, will fit into the cache". I'm not enough of an expert on solr to distinguish which parts of your index are really critical (I think you get the breakdown with that STATUS action). You're probably better off planning for the whole thing. You can add #solr to this question to see if we get some more advice on this from a solr expert.

Comment: In your situation with the 3m.xl's I would try out a 12gb heap and see how that performs.

Comment: so if use recommended 14GB heap, plus lets say 2.5GB for index, would be setting a minimum base of 17GB for 6MM records.  Obviously would want to push up to the 30GB machine images on AWS.., and doing around 40x for sizing 250MM records would mean just over 100GB needed for solr index across the cluster, so with ~15GB available for solr index per node, would need ~8 nodes for starter cluster?  or am I missing something?